# Join on tables that have multiple records against same id

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

`applicant_personal_info` looks like this:

```
A_id         FirstName        LastName
 1            Fahad            Subzwari
```

`applicant_professional_info` table looks like this:

```
A_id       JobOrganization    JobDuration     TotalExperience
 1             10Pearls          12 Months       20 Months
 1               Axact            8 Months       20 Months
```

I want to select data from both tables and have tried this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(aper.FirstName,aper.LastName) AS Name, 
apro.totalExperience '+
'FROM applicant_personal_info aper INNER JOIN applicant_professional_info 
 apro ON '+
 'aper.ApplicantID = apro.ApplicantID WHERE aper.ApplicantID =
```

But this query is returning Name 2 times as there are 2 records in the `applicant_professional_info` table like this:

```
 {
   Name : Fahad Subzwari, Fahad Subzwari,
   TotalExperience: 20 Months
 }
```

But I want a result like this:

```
 {
   Name : Fahad Subzwari,
   TotalExperience: 20 Months
 }
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(aper.FirstName,' ',aper.LastName)) AS Name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT apro.totalExperience)  totalExperience
FROM applicant_personal_info aper 
INNER JOIN applicant_professional_info apro ON aper.ApplicantID = apro.ApplicantID
GROUP BY aper.ApplicantID
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/AOL25376)

**Sample Output**

```
=================================
Name            totalExperience  
--------------  -----------------
Fahad Subzwari  20 Months  
=================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` keyword might be what you need. It allows for filtering duplicates from the query result.

More info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Your select statement would look identical with the small addition of the `distinct` keyword after `select`.

Comment: i have tried this also. but still it is returning Name 2 times

Comment: i have tried this query too
SELECT DISTINCT (GROUP_CONCAT(aper.FirstName,aper.LastName)) AS Name, apro.totalExperience '+
  'FROM applicant_personal_info aper INNER JOIN applicant_professional_info apro ON '+
  'aper.ApplicantID = apro.ApplicantID WHERE aper.ApplicantID =

Comment: Only now I've realized the source of the issue. Do you only receive one ```TotalExperience``` in your result?

Comment: Yes i am receiving only one  totalExperience but multiple times "Name"'